# How get TextView id from table row

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I draw table top and then table body. In each table cell I have TextView, so how can I get it's id or another number, when user clicked on it?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TableLayout lTableLayout;
    lTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbLayout);

    /*Draw table top*/
    TableRow trTop = new TableRow(this);
    trTop.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
    trTop.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(102, 178, 255));
    lTableLayout.addView(trTop, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    String[] str = new String[]{"Time", "Room1", "Room2"};
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        tv1.setTextSize(14);
        tv1.setText(str[j]);
        trTop.addView(tv1,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
    /*Draw table body*/
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

        final TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
        tr1.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);



        if((i%2) == 0)
            tr1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        lTableLayout.addView(tr1, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){

            final TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            tv1.setTextSize(12);
            if(j==0){
                tv1.setText(8+i + ":00");
            }else{
                tv1.setText("reserved");
            }
            tr1.addView(tv1,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id = " + tv1.getId(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("TAG", " clicked ID: " + tr1.getId());
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Here I'm looking for id:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id = " + tv1.getId(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("TAG", " clicked ID: " + tr1.getId());
                }
            });
```

But TOAST says : "id = -1" for each textview.

Comment: `setid()` programmatically  for textviews, like this, `tv.setid(j);`

Comment: thanks a lot!! Its very helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id = " + tv1.getId(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("TAG", " clicked ID: " + tr1.getId());
                }
            });
```

Seems like you're expecting to get a log.e() with **tv1**.getId() and it says **tr1**.getId(), so you're getting the Table row Id and not the TextView Id. Try changing tr1 to tv1 and tell me if it worked.

EDIT:

Everytime you create a textview and a table row, assign them Ids manually with `tr1.setId(i)` and `tv1.setId(j)`. It should work with that.

Comment: in log I tried get tablerow id, and in Toast -- TextView id at a same time.

Comment: they bought have similar answer get id = "-1"

Comment: So I guess it's giving you Id = -1 for every item 'cause it's a default value. I would try doing what this answer says in the edited part (Now I'll edit it)

Comment: ok, now I'm using setid(); like this: tv1.setid(100+i*10+j); It helped me to foundout cell in my table later.